# Azure and signing keys issues. Works with cure but not completely in python

Tags: python, azure

Very puzzled here - in python using requests I can use GET/POST to do a few different things: POST to request a token, and GET to get public signing key x/y coordinates.  And in curl I can sign.  But in python it errors.

This works in CURL:

```
curl -vs -d '{"alg":"ES256", "value":"***"}' -H "Authorization: Bearer REDACTED" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://REDACTED.vault.azure.net/keys/REDACTED/REDACTED/sign?api-version=7.0
```

but in python this fails:

```
post_payload = {'alg':'ES256', 'value':'***'}
post_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer REDACTED', 'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
response = post('https://REDACTED.vault.azure.net/keys/REDACTED/REDACTED/sign?api-version=7.0', data=post_payload, headers=post_headers)
print(response.text)
{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"Property  has invalid value\r\n"}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the request body is encoded to JSON?

Comment: Please hide the key value in your question.

Comment: that wasnt a key, it was just a hashed public transaction that required a signature.
but yes thanks - that was form encoding, I used json= and now it works (yes im new to python)